# Why does adding printf make the function return the right output?

Tags: c++, printf

```cpp
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, int B) {
  int size = static_cast<int>(A.size());
  int max = 0;
  // printf("%d ",size);
  // printf("%d %d ",A[0],A[size-1]);
  int temp = 0, t2 = 0;
  for (int i = -1; i < B; i++) {
    if (i != -1)
      temp += A[i];
    t2 = temp;
    for (int j = size - 1; j > (size - B + i); j--)
      t2 += A[j];
    if (t2 > max)
      max = t2;
  }
  return max;
}
```

When I run this code the value of max returned is 0 when the print statements are commented. When I use the print statements, the value returned is correct. Can anyone help me to understand as to why this is happening? OR if there is a workaround the problem? (I don't want to printing any output through its function). Using printf with empty quotations or NULL does not seem to resolve the issue either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that without the `printf()`, your code doesn't work, but with the `printf()`, your code works?

Comment: When you run into situations like this where a seemingly unrelated line of code completely changes the behavior you are often times running into a case where some error somewhere else is causing undefined behavior.  You may be accessing a bad pointer, overwriting an array, or doing some other thing that affects the memory in a way that you don't expect.  Adding the line of code changes how things are arranged in memory and suddenly the array that was overwritten isn't clobbering good data or the good value is left at the location pointed to by the bad pointer.

Comment: Most likely the real problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Can you give us more context as a [mcve] so we can see the input to this function?

Comment: You're seeing symptoms of some code in your program tromping memory it shouldn't (e.g. running past the end of an array). Adding/removing a call of `printf()` changes your program's layout of memory, so changes what is at the memory location (or memory locations) being tromped, so changes the consequences/symptoms. Within the code you have shown, potential contributors are `i` or `j` going outside the range of `0` to `A.size() - 1` so using them as indices runs outside bounds of `A`.  Without a [mcve] (like a working example that calls your function) a more specific guess is impossible.

Comment: @DynamicSquid yes that is what seems to be happening.

Comment: @Delta_G and Peter thanks for the suggestions.  This was a Black Box problem I encountered (I'm only given the function to work with) so I suppose further exploration is not permissible. If the problem lies elsewhere then it seems there is nothing that can be done.

Comment: Could you provide the data you test?